# How to simplify embedded mysql query into a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

I recently read something about performance problems with embedded mysql queries, so I wanted to know how I could change the following to a "JOIN" (supposedly with better performance?).

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_name_url` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_status` enum('online','offline') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'offline'
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_articles` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_title` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;
```

The logic is basically to select all the categories that have articles associated with them. Each row in the blog_articles table includes a `category_name`
And here is the query I'm using (which checks out and works fine):

```
$sql = "SELECT category_name
     , category_name_url 
   FROM blog_categories 
   WHERE (
     (SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM blog_articles, blog_categories 
      WHERE blog_articles.category_name = blog_categories.category_name
     ) > 0 
     AND blog_categories.category_status = 'online')";
```

I'm still new to "JOIN", and am not sure how to change it when using "COUNT(*)" in the mix too.

Comment: Jay: Also: can you rexamine your query above, and tell us in words the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Thanks for your replies!  The logic is basically to select all the categories that have articles associated with them.  Each row in the `blog_articles` table includes a "category_name".

Comment: and check out www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/ for more on JOINs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than `COUNT(*) > 0`, use [`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
"SELECT category_name, category_name_url FROM blog_categories WHERE EXISTS (" . 
              "(SELECT 1 FROM blog_articles INNER JOIN blog_categories 
                ON blog_articles.category_name = blog_categories.category_name)  AND " . 
              "blog_categories.category_status = 'online'" . 
              ")";
```

This is the old style join syntax:

```
SELECT 1 FROM blog_articles, blog_categories 
WHERE blog_articles.category_name = blog_categories.category_name
```

This is the ANSI form of the same:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM blog_articles
INNER JOIN blog_categories 
    ON blog_articles.category_name = blog_categories.category_name
```

**Update** (in response to posters comments): This query does what you require:

```
"SELECT category_name, category_name_url 
 FROM blog_categories 
 WHERE category_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT category_name FROM blog_articles)
 AND blog_categories.category_status = 'online'"
```

Comment: I think `blog_categories` in the subquery is redundant (both in the OP's query and in yours). There idea seems to be to select only those categories that have articles associated with them. But the actual script (i.e. both your version and @Jay's) will select either all categories or none, depending whether there's at least one article in the database.

Comment: The subquery should probably be `(SELECT * FROM blog_articles WHERE blog_articles.category_name = blog_categories.category_name)`.

Comment: @Andriy M : I was hasty and didn't examine the posters logic! I'll update. Thanks.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Could you explain the "SELECT 1" part?  I've never seen this before (and just did a google search but wasn't able to find a clear answer).

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: And thank you for the "EXISTS" tip - I didn't know about that!

Comment: Depending on your RDBMS,  SELECT * might also be fine. The optimiser should be able to figure out, we want to know if something meets the criteria but we don't require any specific data returned.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `EXISTS`:

```
$sql = "SELECT category_name
             , category_name_url 
        FROM blog_categories 
        WHERE EXISTS
          ( SELECT * 
            FROM blog_articles 
            WHERE blog_articles.category_name = blog_categories.category_name
          ) 
        AND blog_categories.category_status = 'online'
       ";
```

or `JOIN`:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.category_name
             , c.category_name_url 
        FROM blog_categories AS c 
          JOIN blog_articles AS a
            ON a.category_name = c.category_name
        WHERE c.category_status = 'online'
        GROUP BY c.category_name
       ";
```

---

@Jay: I doubt your query as it is, shows only categories that have articles posted. It counts all articles from all categories and then either shows all categories (if the count is > 0) or no categories at all (if the count = 0).

The reason is that the `blog_categories` in your subquery is not related to the `blog_categories` in the main query by any condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
SELECT category_name, category_name_url
FROM blog_categories
WHERE category_id IN (
    SELECT blog_categories.category_id
    FROM blog_articles
    INNER JOIN blog_categories
        ON blog_categories.category_name = blog_articles.category_name
        AND blog_categories.category_status = 'online'
)
```

Comment: -1, `IN (SELECT` is notoriously slow. You should never use it in MySQL, use `where exists` instead.